# Creating validation for user input in windows forms via visual basic code?

Tags: vb.net

I have 5 fields on my form which I need to validate on lost focus and save button. These fields must be mandatory. Searching through google I have find useful tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13922/Validate-user-input-in-Windows-Forms

but I don't want to install some "Validator.dll" in order to achieve this, I want to have code on lost focus event and save button. How can I do this for 5 fields?

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance!
Adi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code

```
if textbox1.text=""then
msgbox "mandatory field!!!"
else 
your code
```

write above code on submit button
i hope this which you want... :)